# jQuery .find() return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 nav tabs on my page and some of then have a YouTube player. So I created a funcion to detect, when a tab is clicked, if previous tab has a player and then stop the video.

```
$('.home-section').on('show.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (event) {
  if (typeof event.relatedTarget  !== "undefined") {
    var tab = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('href');
    var player = $(tab).find($('#youtube')).get(0);
    pauseVideo(player);
  }
});
```

But now, I have a nav tabs inside a pane and this function is not working. The `tab` variable return the correct id, but `player` variable always return undefined.

Comment: Use `$('#youtube').get(0)` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please correct

```
$('.home-section').on('show.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (event) {
  if (typeof event.relatedTarget  !== "undefined") {
    var tab = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('href');
    var player = $(tab).find('#youtube').get(0);
    pauseVideo(player);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, only in this line:

```
var player = $(tab).find($('#youtube')).get(0);
```

you must pass the `selector` (`#youtube`) to `find()` function no the `jQuery` elem:

```
var player = $(tab).find('#youtube').get(0);
```